# laravel redirecting using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I am trying to redirect to the file that was uploaded using ajax.

I can redirect to the uploaded file in my laravel controller using this:

**uploadcontroller.php**

```
return redirect('art/'.$image->id);
```

but how can I translate the above to a ajax redirect instead?

**.js**

```
myDropzone.on("success", function(file, response) {

  window.location.href = '/art/';  

});
```

I don't understand how to pass the variable to js.

Comment: I dont think there is any difference between laravel redirect and window.location.href ....

Comment: you have to return the image id in your laravel function into your ajax request and use this one. Define your base url first.
 window.location.href = baseurl + '/art/'+file;

Answer (score 0):

```js
myDropzone.on("success", function(file, response) {

  window.location.href = "{{url('art/'.$image->id)}}";  

});
```